# c++ debug jump back netbeans and eclipse

Tags: 12.04, eclipse, c++, netbeans, debug

All the latest netbean ide and eclipse ide for c++

open some project and then rebuild and debug, it will somehow jump back to somewhere when I press step over,like this (from 44 to 40):

[image]

Can someone help?

UBUNTU 12.04 ,64bits, java 1.7.0_51